# Google Spreadsheet Script Editor Code For Hiding Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am using Google Sheets and using the script editor. I am trying to create a function where if cell B4=2 then cells B5;B10 and Cells C5;C10 will be hidden within the google spreadsheet

Comment: How will B4 be set to 2? A user edit perhaps?

Comment: I don't know of any way to hide a cell.  You can hide a row or column, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

## Camouflaging Cells

This assumes that the change in B4 is from a user edit of B4.

You can hide rows, hide columns and hide sheets, but currently you cannot really hide cells.

This won't actually hide the cells but it will make it difficult to read by making the font color and background color identical and if you wish to go that way you can also protect them.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet2'){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==4) {
    e.source.toast('Flag');
    var rg1=sh.getRange('B5:B10');
    var rg2=sh.getRange('C5:C10');
    if(e.value==2) {
      rg1.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      rg2.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      rg1.setBackground('#ffffff');
      rg2.setBackground('#ffffff');
    }else
    {
      rg1.setFontColor('#000000');
      rg2.setFontColor('#000000');
      rg1.setBackground('#ffffff');
      rg2.setBackground('#ffffff');
    }
  }
}
```

This also adds and removes protection.  This is untested.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var ss=e.source;
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet2'){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==4) {
    e.source.toast('Flag');
    var rg1=sh.getRange('B5:B10');
    var rg2=sh.getRange('C5:C10');
    if(e.value==2) {
      rg1.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      rg2.setFontColor('#ffffff');
      rg1.setBackground('#ffffff');
      rg2.setBackground('#ffffff');
      rg1.protect();
      rg2.protect();
    }else
    {
      rg1.setFontColor('#000000');
      rg2.setFontColor('#000000');
      rg1.setBackground('#ffffff');
      rg2.setBackground('#ffffff');
      var protections=ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      for (var i=0;i<protections.length;i++) {
        var protection = protections[i];
        if (protection.canEdit()) {
          protection.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

[sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRow(Range))